# How to find username and password with filezilla and apache

Tags: apache, passwords, filezilla

I'm trying to use FileZilla to connect to my own Apache server, but I can't figure out what the username and password should be for the server. Is there any way to find these values, or some sort of defaults I should try? Sorry for the stupid question, this is basically my first time working with any sort of server.

Comment: You're using FileZilla to connect to Apache? I think you made a mistake. FileZilla is a file transfer client, Apache is a server. What I think you mean is that _you are trying to connect FileZilla to the server which has Apache running on it_.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I mean, thanks

Comment: Was that the issue? Did my suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is trying to connect to the server that contains your Apache installation, then all you have to do is connect to it using the IP address of the server on your network (example: 192.168.1.10), enter a valid username and corresponding password of a user on that machine, and you should be able to connect.

Refer to this document for more details:

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_Client_Tutorial_(en)#Connecting_to_a_server